# program to input student details , modules studied by student , marks of exam , and calculate gpa and write results to txt file using python

Tags: python-3.x

Assignment that i need help on

[image]

how the results should be present
[image]

the code i tried coming up with
[image]

part of the code i was writting
[image]

results from the code i've written
[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem that you need assistance with?

Comment: writing a code that would create a transcript file to txt document

Comment: That is not a specific problem. On Stack Overflow, people can assist with solving specific problems, such as why your transcript file returns xyz when you use the abc() function. In your case, you are just saying here is my incorrect output, please help. That is too general for Stack Overflow.

Comment: OK  i get you now